# "A network error has occurred" error on email/password sign up with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

I'm following the setup for email/password sign up that Firebase has specified in their official documentation; however, I keep getting "a network error has occurred" error when proceeding with authentication.

Authentication code:

```
window.onload = function() {
  const config = {
        apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  const btnSignUp = document.getElementById('btnSignUp');

  btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const inputEmail = document.getElementById('username-input');
    const inputPassword = document.getElementById('password-input');

    const email = inputEmail.value;
    const password = inputPassword.value;
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,    password).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
  });
};
```

Console errors:

```
A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
```

Comment: Please provide more information on the environment you are using. Can you also check your network log. Is the request going out? That should help explain things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All set - the problem was the 'type' attribute in the button was not defined and was defaulted to a submit type. By setting type="button", the issue was resolved.

Comment: I was having the same problem, how does setting the type to button resolved this issue?

Comment: @KaoriYui If the button is of type submit and it is inside a form tag, it will trigger the action defined in the form tag, if there isn't any action, a refresh is also triggered. When this happens, the authentication request to Firebase gets interrupted and the error is thrown. By setting the type to button, this mitigates that error from happening.